# Draw Again/Refresh after change the size of the window

Tags: c, winapi, drawing

When I choose in my popup menu draw a line, It can draw a aline.

Now I will change the size of the opening window with my cursor and make it smaller or bigger or else, the line disappear.

How can the line redraw or refresh after I change the height/width of the programm while it running?

I think there must be someting in WM_Paint, but dont know what.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code which draws the line in WM_PAINT.
Add example of the code to make the answer more detailed.

Comment: Yeah but i have WM_PAINT and WM_COMMAND and in the WM_COMMAND there is the IDM_DrawLine. So i must put WM_COMMAND into WM_PAINT or what?

Comment: IDM_DrawLine - this one in WM_PAINT

Comment: But I just wanna draw the line only when the button drawline is pressed !!!!!! and not draw it directly !!!!!!!!!! Read please first